# Add n values together to get x in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array of values (about 20 of them), ranging from about `9.5` to `0.001`. I need to add the values together to get a number anywhere between 15 and 85 (Or get the nearest value possible)

Test data:

```
[9.912,7.414,5.512, 5.43,5.303,5.041,5.025,4.944,3.509,  3.3,3.191,3.076,2.914,2.753, 2.29,1.955,1.917,1.822,1.626,1.526,1.489,1.482,1.362,1.354,1.311,1.222,1.154,0.904,0.799, 0.79,0.657,0.643,0.618,0.615,0.592,0.564,0.484, 0.48,0.447,0.419,0.415,0.328,0.325,0.288, 0.26,0.251,0.248,0.23,0.223,0.221,0.154,0.129,0.128,0.126,0.103,0.102,0.099,0.092,0.077,0.071,0.066, 0.06,0.046,0.037,0.028,0.023,0.007,0.003,0.003,0.003,0.002,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001]
```

Can anyone help me/is this even possible?

Comment: You've not shown any of your own code or any indication you've tried researching/searching for a solution. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!) I'd recommend reading [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as at the moment your question is missing the basics that are expected when asking a question. Your question is likely to be downvoted and closed until you include the basics.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a class assignment question to me...

Comment: Yes, ill do that next time. My main problem is just that i had no clue at all how to even approach this (Therefore had no code). Now that i see the awnser it seems so clear!

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The nearest value to a range 15..85? What is the aim, lower/upper end of the range? Or get an exact integer value? To match a distinct value a backtracking algorythm might find better values other than just adding up in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
$arr = @(9.912,7.414,5.512, 5.43,5.303,5.041,5.025,4.944,3.509,  3.3,3.191,3.076,2.914,2.753, 2.29,1.955,1.917,1.822,1.626,1.526,1.489,1.482,1.362,1.354,1.311,1.222,1.154,0.904,0.799, 0.79,0.657,0.643,0.618,0.615,0.592,0.564,0.484, 0.48,0.447,0.419,0.415,0.328,0.325,0.288, 0.26,0.251,0.248,0.23,0.223,0.221,0.154,0.129,0.128,0.126,0.103,0.102,0.099,0.092,0.077,0.071,0.066, 0.06,0.046,0.037,0.028,0.023,0.007,0.003,0.003,0.003,0.002,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001)

$output = 0
$arr | foreach {
    if(($output + $_) -le 85){
        $output += $_
    }
}

$output
```

The above example will return a number close to but less than 85